# Is there any way to spllit actions and bind some of them to specific reducer?

Tags: redux

I'm new to Redux, i'm apoligize if my question is trivial, but i can't find answer for that.

I have several reducers combine with combineReducers() and one big ActionCreator.js with all actions what i have.

Is there some kind good-practice-way for split this ActionCreator to a several files and bind specific Action file to specific reducer in order to increase productivity and simplify code reading?

```js
//reducer.js:
    
    import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
    import { authReducer} from './authReducer';
    import { modalHandler } from './modalHandler';
    import { rootReducer } from './rootReducer';
    import { errorHandler } from './errorHandler';
    
    const reducer = combineReducers({ authReducer, modalHandler, rootReducer, errorHandler });
    
    export default reducer;
    
    
    //ActionCreator.js:
    
    export const newMessage = (id, mess)=> {
      return dispatch => {
        return axios.post('/api/channel/newMessage', {id, mess})
          .then(res => {
            dispatch(getChannelData());
          })
          .catch(err => {
            dispatch(requestError(err));
          });
      };
    };
    
    export const channelLogoUpload = formData => {
      return dispatch => {
        return axios.post('/api/uploads/newChannel/logo', formData)
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.url)
            dispatch(newLogo(res.data.url))
          })
          .catch(err => dispatch(requestError(err)));
      }
    }
    
    export const userRegistration = user => {
      console.log(user);
      return dispatch => {
        return axios.post('/api/signup', { user })
          .then(res => {
            if (res.status === 200) {
              dispatch(newUser(true));
            }
          })
          .catch(err => {
            if (err) {
              dispatch(registrationError(err.response.data.message));
            }
          })
      }
    }
    
    export const imageIncrease = (value, title) => ({
      type: IMAGE_INCREASE,
      value,
      title
    });
    
    export const logOut = () => ({
      type: LOG_OUT
    });
    
    //...etc
    
    
    // I want something like this:
     
    const combineReducers({
       authActions: authReducer,
       modalActions: modalHandler,
      //...etc
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what are the standard practices but in my previous project we used to write all action creators in the same file as its reducer.Then we used to combine all these reducers together.This way you can change action creators that effect to a particular reducer.

Comment: thanks for this tip, I'll read about how reducers works and think about it.